# Why is my terminal looking this way?

Tags: unity

I'll be brief; I was careless with synaptic and end up causing problems to myself. I fixed most of the problems but now my terminal is looking like this:

[image: My terminal]

I have tried everything that came to my mind and i don't know what else to do. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You probably uninstalled Unity Terminal. `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` and the a reboot should fix it.

Comment: What is wrong with your terminal. Other than it looks like you used a password to name your computer? Some like series of names from favorite movies or groups. I just use model & Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thanks Zacharee1 what you said helped me.  What is wrong is that i couldn't even open a terminal from a file and i liked how it looks with the gnome-terminal  to be honest. But now it's fine, thank everyone

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned in the comments,you've most likely uninstantiated the `gnome-terminal` , the default terminal app for Ubuntu and Unity.

In that case the solution is `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

On the other hand, the possibility could also be that it was replaced with `xterm` as default terminal app. Ubuntu by default ships with two terminal apps, `gnome-terminal` and `xterm` (the last one being the classic terminal app, and is installed pretty much across the linux distros with Xorg graphical server).

To fix the defaults issue, run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` and select `gnome-terminal.wrapper` from the list of choices.

For instance, here's my output. Don't be surprised - I've installed a lot of terminal apps

```
$ sudo update-alternatives  --config x-terminal-emulator               
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
There are 9 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/konsole                  40        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/mlterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/sakura                   40        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  8            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  9            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```